# SP2010 Push custom edit, new, disp Form for a calendar list (event list)

Tags: development

Through SPDesigner you can create your own edit, new and dispForm pages and enable them as the default ones for your list.

I was wondring if it's possible to push these files to existing lists in sites or at site provisiong with some code behind?